# Python Dictionary to List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to take a dictionary i made with pygeocodio and print a list out from only the county key in the dictionary.

Here is an example of my dictionary

```
[{'input': {'address_components': {'number': '1600', 'street': 'Pennsylvania', 'suffix': 'Ave', 'postdirectional': 'SE', 'formatted_street': 'Pennsylvania Ave SE', 'city': 'Washington', 'state': 'DC', 'zip': '20003', 'country': 'US'}, 'formatted_address': '1600 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, DC 20003'}, 'results': [{'address_components': {'number': '1600', 'street': 'Pennsylvania', 'suffix': 'Ave', 'postdirectional': 'SE', 'formatted_street': 'Pennsylvania Ave SE', 'city': 'Washington', **'county': 'District of Columbia'**, 'state': 'DC', 'zip': '20003', 'country': 'US'}, 'formatted_address': '1600 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, DC 20003', 'location': {'lat': 38.879138, 'lng': -76.981879}, 'accuracy': 1, 'accuracy_type': 'rooftop', 'source': 'DC Geographic Information Systems Program (DC GIS)'}]}, {'input': {'address_components': {'number': '3101', 'street': 'Patterson', 'suffix': 'Ave', 'formatted_street': 'Patterson Ave', 'city': 'Richmond', 'state': 'VA', 'zip': '23221', 'country': 'US'}, 'formatted_address': '3101 Patterson Ave, Richmond, VA 23221'}, 'results': [{'address_components': {'number': '3101', 'street': 'Patterson', 'suffix': 'Ave', 'formatted_street': 'Patterson Ave', 'city': 'Richmond', **'county': 'Richmond city'**, 'state': 'VA', 'zip': '23221', 'country': 'US'}, 'formatted_address': '3101 Patterson Ave, Richmond, VA 23221', 'location': {'lat': 37.560446, 'lng': -77.476008}, 'accuracy': 1, 'accuracy_type': 'rooftop', 'source': 'Virginia GIS Clearinghouse'}]}]
```

The name of the dictionary is `LocationTest`

This what im currently doing in my python terminal

```
>>> from geocodio import GeocodioClient
>>> client = GeocodioClient(MY_KEY)
>>> locationTest = client.geocode(['1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC','3101 Patterson Ave, Richmond, VA, 23221'])
>>> list(zip(*(locationTest[key] for key in keys)))
```

then i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <genexpr>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

i then ran this

```
list_key_value = [ [k,v] for k, v in locationTest.items()]
```

and recieved this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'LocationCollection' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Ultimately i want to be able to save all of the County key/value pairs to a csv file in a list or excel spreadsheet?

Comment: You actually have a _list_ inside which there is a dictionary. Try working the problem that way.

Comment: As  @BurhanKhalid said, `locationTest` is actually a `List` not `dict`, I would suggest also check the geocodio docs to see what's the return value of `GeocodioClient.geocode` and what methods does it supported